# Toilet Paper Problem

Tags: geometry

I've tried 5 ways to do the problem but I'm not getting to 202-206? Could it be an author mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to

> $(2.5+1.5)^2-1.5^2$ is to $528$ as $(1.25+1.5)^2-1.5^2$ is to `???`.

Also note that $(a+b)^2-a^2=(2a+b)b$, as that *might* help.